# how to send response to dialogflow

Tags: java, apache-spark, dialogflow-es

I am trying to do a facebook chatbot messenger using dialogflow v2.
I configured webhook url in Dialogflow.I am getting the request from dialogflow.
But the problem is i am not clear about how to send the response to dialogflow.

Below is my code

```
post("/", (request, response) -> {
            String body = request.body();
            System.err.println(body);
            String reply = "Hi";
            JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject google = new JSONObject();
            google.put("expectUserResponse", true);
            JSONObject richResponse = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray itemsArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject simpleResponseRoot = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject simpleResponse = new JSONObject();
            simpleResponse.put("textToSpeech", reply);
            simpleResponseRoot.put("simpleResponse", simpleResponse);
            itemsArray.put(simpleResponseRoot);
            richResponse.put("items", itemsArray);
            google.put("richResponse", richResponse);
            payload.put("google", google);
            responseJSON.put("payload", payload);
            System.err.println(responseJSON);
            return responseJSON;
        });
```

Below is my json response

```
{"payload":{"google":{"richResponse":{"items":[{"simpleResponse":{"textToSpeech":"Hi"}}]},"expectUserResponse":true}}}
```

But i am not getting this response to my facebook page.

Can anyone share the code or json format to send the dialogflow.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the reply format for Actions on Google, which contains additional information than used by other integrations. You probably want JSON more like

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "Hi"
}
```